# Using Environment Variables in Angular Node Package

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am creating an angular 4 node package for a logging service that we have created.  Is it possible to use the angular cli environment variables to set the default path for the service?  If so, how should the path be defined for the environment file?

I am following these instructions for creating the node package:
https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464

I followed these examples for setting up environment variables:
http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/

https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the [forRoot](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#!#core-for-root) methodology explained in the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#!#core-for-root).

Inside of your external Angular library modify the main exported module to have this structure:

```
export class MyLibraryModule {
  static forRoot(config: configData): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyLibraryModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: AppConfigModel, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }

  constructor(@Optional() config: AppConfigModel) {
    if (config) { /* Save config data */ }
  }

 }

 export class AppConfigModel {
    defaultPath: string;
 }
```

When you import this module into your application, use the forRoot static method and pass in the config data.

```
imports: [
    MyLibraryModule.forRoot({ defaultPath: environment.defaultPath }),
 ]
```

On a side note, I use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular2-library) for creating my Angular npm modules.  It simplifies the process quite a bit.